# how to ignore charters such as /, + , $ as String in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose have I a `String` that looks like this `_string = ‘deje$AA/AQ+AJ’`

is their a way to **ignore** all if the charters within that `_string`  such as  `/ , $` as single `String` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using 'replaceAll' method.

[image]

```
_string = _string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[/\+]'), '');
```

Comment: what if thier was a `$`, can i use replace all aswell ?

Comment: _string = _string.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[/\+$]'), '');

Comment: You can do by understanding regex grammar. Just add a character that you want to delete at between '[ ]'.